# Получить файл через resourceId

Tags: java, android, строки, android-resources

У меня есть id ресурса-строка из файла R. например: 21346466556.
Это mp3 файл в папке raw. Как мне его преобразовать в File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mContext.getResources().getResourceEntryName(Integer.parseInt("ResourceId")));
```